# Crash Consensus Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, pseudocode

I am having problems implementing the Crash Consensus Algorithm.
Here is some pseudo code. Can someone please give me a an explanation on what it means.

```
Crash-Consensus-Receive-Message(m)
if m is proposal message then
    ▷add the received values to set of all known proposed values
    add[knownValues,values[m]]
    note that sender[m]has not crashed during this round
else                ▷ordinary message received
process message m

Crash-Consensus-Reach-Consensus()
knownValues←{ownValue}  ▷start with just own proposed value
sentValues←0            ▷no values sent yet
for i←0 to f do         ▷f+1 rounds of multicasts
      ▷determine which known values have not yet been sent
      newValues←knownValues -ssentValues
      multicast proposal message with newValues to alive processes
      wait until next round
use pre-agreed strategy with knownValues to get consensus value
```

What does it mean by sender[m] and values[m] as the m means message here? Also what does it mean by knownValues.

Comment: Don''t post screenshots of textual information!

Comment: Whichever book this is from (maybe mention that in your question?) will probably have a 'syntax conventions' section near the beginning. That might offer some guidance.

Comment: i was planing to type it, but i didn't no how to type a triangle. Whats wrong with screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

In the most of programming languages the square brackets mean an array of values, in your case an array of knowed messages or an array of messeges to send. I'm not sure if this is also true in pseudo code but I think maybe can help you in all case.